# cutting rim joist to run range hood ducting?

Tags: joists

We are looking to add an island range hood and ideally would like for a ducted system and not a ductless/recirculating. Kitchen is in the 1st floor corner of a 2-story home. The spanning floor joists are 2x10 (the ones running left to right in the pic). On top of the floor joists sit another set of 2x8 floor joists that run perpendicular (this is for a bathroom area that is raised 1 step on the floor above).

Our thought was that we could cut through the 2x8 rim joist (which sits on top of the 2x10 end joist) and run the ducting there, but since there is a 2nd story above it, I was told by one contractor that this can't be done since that rim joist is load bearing, and then another told me the opposite that it can be done with no issue.

Most range hoods use either 6" or 8" ducts--either way this means I would effectively need to cut through the entire width of the rim joist. Can this be done? I'm including a pic of the kitchen layout as well.

[image]

Comment: 2nd contractor is correct

Comment: If it makes you feel better, you could use a 3.25x14 duct and wall vent at the rim joist.

Comment: Can you install this hood & duct? Yes. Can you do it _this way_? Probably not. To figure out how you'll probably need the services of a Structural Engineer to ensure that it's done in a way that won't damage your house. The short term cost will be more than made up for by the _lack_ of long term damage.

Comment: Basically the same split response I got from differing contractors.  I had another come out to take a look, and they at first said it is a simple job and can be done with no issues.  When I asked if this would be with city permits and such, the proposal ballooned to 5 figures to have structural engineer review and draw up plans.